# Angular2 routes clash inconsistant

Tags: angular, router

I have two Angular2 routes like this:

```
{
  path: '/campaigns/tiles',
  component: TileComponent,
},
{
  path: 'campaigns/:id',
  component: CampaignComponent,
}
```

If I click from within the app (`[routerLink]="'/campaigns/tiles;edit=' + tileId"`), the tiles route is matched and TileComponent works its magic.

If I go to the route directly (e.g. reload or type in url) with the first url (e.g. save and the url reloads: `http://localhost:5555/campaigns/tiles;edit=5873c41da698e48d387a3bca`), my `CampaignsComponent` is complaining about `tiles;edit=blah` not being a proper campaign Id. (Well not CampaignComponent, but the backend, but still.).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about `http://localhost:5555/campaigns/tiles?edit=5873c41da698e48d387a3bca`? (`?` instead of `;`)

Comment: Besides that, how should we know why some of your code complains?

Comment: Well, I don't think it's my code. The part I'm asking about is Angular code. In one case, it renders one component, in other, it renders another component. I'd like to know what I did wrong (or maybe Angular) so I can improve my route config.

Comment: What is the exact complaint?

Comment: No complaint. I am just confused. If I link to an url as `[routerLink]="'/campaigns/tiles?edit=5873c41da698e48d3‌​87a3bca'"` angular will open one component. If I open that url directly, it will open the other component. And it's consistent in that. So I'm guessing I overlooked something and I want to find out what.

Or my understanding of the router is wrong, and I should expect Angular to render routes differently if it's within the page or url open externally. If that's the case, I want to learn.

Comment: "is complaining about tiles;edit=blah not being a proper campaign Id. " what does that mean then?

Comment: It means it went to fetch the campaign by id: `tiles;edit=5873c41da698e48d3‌​87a3bca`. So it rendered /campaigns/tiles;edit=.... as /campaigns/:id - why? There's a matching route before that one.